# Disable left and right movement of mouse when dragging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have implemented a simple Drag and drop list using jQuery (not HTML5).

It is working fine, but I am able to drag the list elements a bit too much and not just within the list (I am not able to drop them, ofcourse).

Here is a photo:

[image]

Here is the short and simple code that I used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

How do I restrain the amount of area for the dragged element to just up and down movement and not any left - right movement at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$("#sortable" ).sortable({axis: 'y'});

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-axis